# CATransition also animating the navigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, catransition

I want to make a custom animation to pop my navigation controller. I only want to animate the view, not the navigationBar. With this code I animate both, the view and the navigationBar. How can I only animate the view??

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

this code is fired when a custom back button added inside the navigationcontroller bar is pressed.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could tell us where the code snippet from above is executed exactly? (in a delegate method of the tabbar? in another parent view controller?, ...)
Are you calling the above code in a viedDidLoad event maybe?

Comment: @NenadMihajlovic it is called when my default back button in the navigationBar is touched

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that does custom animation both for back button and when you call `popRootViewController:` method.

It's a class that extends `UINavigationViewController` which by itself contradicts Apple's docs also it assigns private variable using KVO, which might stop working as soon as engineers change `UINavigationController` class so use it a t your own risk.

```
#import "MyNavigationController.h"

@interface MyNavigationController () <UINavigationBarDelegate> {
    // Flag that we will use to avoid collisions between navgiation bar
    // when we call popViewControllerAnimated: method directly
    BOOL _isPopping;
}
- (UIViewController *)myPopViewControllerAniamted:(BOOL)animated;
@end

@implementation MyNavigationController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    // We can't intercept delegation of the original navigation bar,
    // we have to replace it with our own, by assigning new instance to
    // the private _navigationBar vairable
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    navigationBar.delegate = self;
    [self setValue:navigationBar forKey:@"_navigationBar"];

    return self;
}

// This is the delegate method called when you're about to pop navigation item
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
// If we're in the process of popping items we don't want to reenter
    if (!_isPopping) {
        [self myPopViewControllerAniamted:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}

// Similarly we have to override popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
// The only difference would be that we use not previous view as a
// target for the transfition, but the very first view
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return [self myPopViewControllerAniamted:animated];
}

// Our custom popping method
- (UIViewController *)myPopViewControllerAniamted:(BOOL)animated
{
    _isPopping = YES;
    // If we got here, we have at least two view controllers in the stack
    UIViewController *currentViewController = self.topViewController;
    if (animated && self.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        UIView *currentView = currentViewController.view;
        UIViewController *previousViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.viewControllers.count - 2];
        UIView *previousView = previousViewController.view;
        previousView.alpha = 0.0;
        [currentView.superview insertSubview:previousView belowSubview:currentView];
        // I use UIView just for the sake of the simplicity of this example
        // In case of core animation you will have to deal with delegates
        // to trigger view controller popping when animation finishes
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            currentView.alpha = 0.0;
            previousView.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            _isPopping = NO;
        }];
    } else {
        [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        _isPopping = NO;
    }
    return currentViewController;
}

@end
```

Once again, it was done purely as exercise of what is possible, I would highly recommend reading [UIViewController guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), probably [Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) can satisfy you needs as a designated way of customizing view controller behaviour.

Hope it helps!